# Run python script in a CI/CD step

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, apim

I am new to DevOps and this whole world, so I would like some help.

I have an existing pipeline created. I also have a python script that I have just created, this script gets a json file, replace some stuff and replace the file content (I tested with a local file). Now I need to add this python code to my pipeline tasks, this task should copy a repository file, and process it.

I Googled trying to find a way of achiving this, but nothing. I do not even know where to place the python script.

Would anyone be able to point me to some direction?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the python script file in [Azure Git Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops) and use the repository as the pipeline source. Then add [`Run a Python script` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/python-script-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) in pipeline and specify the script path like below.

[image]

To [run Python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#run-python-scripts) in your repository, you can also use a script element and specify a filename in YAML pipeline. For example:

```
- script: python src/example.py
```

Comment: Vita, thanks for your answer, do you know how I can then reference a group variable? I tried multiple ways, but it is not working $(var_name) $(VAR_NAME) $(env:var_name) $(env:VAR_NAME)

Comment: Hi RNA, you can refer to the documents [Define variables - Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and [use variables in variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cli/pipeline-variable-group-secret-nonsecret-variables?view=azure-devops) to learn details.